# Rearranging letters but keep the first and last the same

Tags: python

I have to rearrange a five letter word. The code I have right now works in the sense that it rearranges the word but I need it to keep the first and last letters the same. I've tried adding different parts and splitting.

How should I change it to keep these parts the same?

```
def in_lat(word):
    return word[::-1] 

assert (in_lat("first") == "fsrit")
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep the first and last, but only reverse the middle section.  Recall that a slice is a half-open interval, so start from -2 (2nd to last letter) down to but not including 0 (first letter), counting backwards with -1:

```
def in_lat(word):
    return word[0] + word[-2:0:-1] + word[-1]

assert in_lat("first") == "fsrit"
```

You should add a check that the word is at least 4 letters long...

Answer (score 2):

We can use [tuple unpacking<sup>1</sup>](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) here. We just have separated the word as the first character, the middle part of the string and the last character. We can generalize this approach to work with arbitrary-length strings.

```
def func(wrd):  # if we give "abcd" as `wrd`
    if len(wrd) < 2:
        return wrd
    else:
#       'a' ['b', 'c'] 'd'  
#        ‖      ‖      ‖
        first, *mid, last = wrd
        return "".join([first, *mid[::-1], last])
      # return first + "".join(mid[::-1]) + last
```

Sample outputs:

```
In [16]: func("a")                                                              
Out[16]: 'a'

In [17]: func("ab")                                                             
Out[17]: 'ab'

In [18]: func("abc")                                                            
Out[18]: 'abc'

In [19]: func("abcd")                                                           
Out[19]: 'acbd'

In [20]: func("")                                                               
Out[20]: ''
```

---

<sub>1. [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
w   = 'easyone'
val = w[0] + w[-2:0:-1] + w[-1]
```

returns

```
'enoysae'
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69733107/12416453)